# KDB C++ interface - correct way to implement socket timeout

Tags: kdb

I am calling KDB from C using,

```
K res = k(m_conn_fd, s, (K)0 );
```

However, there's no time out parameter.

I read the documentation [here](https://code.kx.com/q/interfaces/c-client-for-q/#socket-timeouts), but it's sparse on details of what would be in res->t when a timeout happens. Is it going to be -128?

Also, what errno code should we be expecting?

Comment: What exactly is `m_conn_fd` ? As per [this doc](https://code.kx.com/q//interfaces/c-client-for-q/#connecting-to-a-q-server), in `int c=khpun("localhost",1234,"myname:mypassword",1000)`, the returned value `c=-2`  is timeout